# Facebook graph API: Filtering page conversations by date

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Anyone know how to filter Facebook page conversations by date? 
My goal is to get all the messages from the date I specified to now.

I tried to query with:

> PAGE-ID/conversations?fields=updated_time&messages{created_time}&since=2017-06-27

and

> PAGE-ID?fields=conversations.since(2017-06-27){updated_time,messages{created_time}}

but it still return threads that later than  2017-06-27.
I am using api v2.9.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This look like this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420363721670492/

Comment: O thank you! I am new to the Facebook API so I did not think it is a bug in the first place.